# DNS record for help.example.com returns 404

Tags: apache, web, dns, cname, a-records

I have a domain `example.com`. I'd like to map `help.example.com` to `example.com`. The DNS records are:

```
Hostname           Type     Value
example.com        A        93.184.216.34
help.example.com   A        93.184.216.34
www.example.com    CNAME    example.com
```

I can access the website with both `example.com` and `www.example.com` but when I try `help.example.com` I get `404 Not Found`.:

> Not Found
>   The requested URL / was not found on this server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

So I'd like to know why is the `A` record for `help.example.com` not redirecting to `example.com`.

---

Extra information:

- My .htaccess consists of the single line:

  ```
  ErrorDocument 404 "Cannot find that URL"
  ```

  If I try to access `example.com/some_random_string` I get (as expected) `Cannot find that URL`. However if I try to access `help.example.com/some_random_string` I get the above `Not Found` message. So it seems that .htaccess is ignored by `help.example.com`
- Pinging `example.com`, `www.example.com`, and `help.example.com` returns the same IP address.
- I also tried to replace the `A` record with:

  ```
  help.example.com   CNAME     example.com
  ```

  But this returns the same `Not Found` message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in webserver configuration. Not in DNS at all.
I assume you use Apache so you need to tell Apache that `example.com` `www.example.com` `help.example.com` have same root directory.
For example if you use VirualHost configuration and Ubuntu then look in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf`
It should have

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com help.example.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

If you use other OS/configuration/WebServer you can google/look how your configuration works and where to add your domain name. Not in DNS.

Comment: Actually now when I think about it you probably didn't setup your server. You probably use some web-hosting service. Then you need to login into your control panel and add `domain` or `alias` there. But hoster may ask additional payment for this. Anyway your DNS works fine, webserver receives your requests, he just doesn't know where `help.example.com` located on disk.

Comment: Awesome I included that `ServerAlias` command in my `example.com.conf` file and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are dots missed in the CNAME record. It should be

```
help.example.com.   CNAME     example.com.
```

So called FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) should be used in CNAME record.
Without the dot nameserver appends the value $origin variable to the end.